# configuring rails application to make ui router work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to implement ui-routing in my rails application but it is not able to find the page to which I want to route to.

The tree structure in rails that I followed is

```
app
 assets
   javascripts
      angular_controllers
         menu_controller.js
   config
      menu_config.js
   templates
      login.html
```

code for **menu_config.js**

```
angular.module('publishingApp')
          .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('login',
{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
})
}]);
```

code for **index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="menuController">
<header ng-class="navClass">
     <nav><img src="assets/sample_image.png"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="login">Signin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
</ul></nav>
</header>
<section>
     <div ui-view></div>
</section>
```

Error which I received when I run the code on browser and click on signin menu option
GET http://localhost:3000/templates/login.html 404 (Not Found)

Now I know am doing something wrong and I don't understand how to configure rails to load the html page.
Please any help is appreciated..

**Update:**

I created a template folder inside public folder and removed the template folder from the app/assets/ and now everything works fine. So which way is a better way to create applications and which way should be followed?